# Reverse loop TicTacToe

Tags: java, loops, refactoring

I've got loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i<3; i++){
  System.out.println(i);
}

output:
0
1
2
```

I need to reverse this loop to output:

```
2
1
0
```

I need it because I work on TicTacToe Java game.

Here is my code for check win:

```
 static boolean checkWin(char dot) {
        for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++) {
                if (map[0][i] == dot && i == 2) {
                    return true;
                }
                if (map[1][i] == dot && i == 2) {
                    return true;
                }

                if (map[2][i] == dot && i == 2) {
                    return true;
                }
                if (map[i][0] == dot && i == 2) {
                    return true;
                }
                if (map[i][1] == dot && i == 2) {
                    return true;
                }
                if (map[i][2] == dot && i == 2) {
                    return true;
                }
                if (map[i][i] == dot && i == 2) {
                    return true;
                }
                if (map[i][0] == dot && i == 2) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

        }
        return false;
    }
```

last thing that I need to refactor this method:

```
  static boolean checkWin(char dot) {
        if (map[0][0] == dot && map[0][1] == dot && map[0][2] == dot) {
            return true;
        }
        if (map[1][0] == dot && map[1][1] == dot && map[1][2] == dot) {
            return true;
        }
        if (map[2][0] == dot && map[2][1] == dot && map[2][2] == dot) {
            return true;
        }

        if (map[0][0] == dot && map[1][0] == dot && map[2][0] == dot) {
            return true;
        }
        if (map[0][1] == dot && map[1][1] == dot && map[2][1] == dot) {
            return true;
        }
        if (map[0][2] == dot && map[1][2] == dot && map[2][2] == dot) {
            return true;
        }

        if (map[0][0] == dot && map[1][1] == dot && map[2][2] == dot) {
            return true;
        }
        if (map[0][2] == dot && map[1][1] == dot && map[2][0] == dot) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

I almost done it.

Last thing that i need refactor this part of code:

```
if (map[0][2] == dot && map[1][1] == dot && map[2][0] == dot) {
   return true;
}
```

to something like

```
  if (map[i][0] == dot && i == 2) {
          return true;
    }
```

Main question is here:

```
for (int i = 0; i<3; i++){
  System.out.println(i);
}

output:
0
1
2
```

I need to reverse this loop to output:

```
2
1
0
```

to feel this last part:

```
  if (map[i][0] == dot && i == 2) {
          return true;
 }
```

i need to feel this last condition with values 2 1 0

```
  if (map[i][insert here] == dot && i == 2) {
          return true;
 }
```

Please Help.

Comment: If you know what you want `i` to start at, when the loop should stop, and how `i` should change each iteration, you have all you need.

Comment: What are you doing that requires counting backwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is reverse the loop output, you can just invert what you're doing in the for loop

```
for (int i = 2; i>=0; i--){
        System.out.println(i);
    }

output:
2
1
0
```

As a quick example.